# SE for logistic regression predictions

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, predict

I have been tasked with calculating the SE for logistic regression point estimates (where all my predictor variables are factors).  I typically use ggpredict to estimate my predictions which provides CI's.  However, we are comparing our results to estimates from program MARK and we find readers have a better grasp at understanding our plots with SE as opposed to 95% CI's.

Based on reading the package notes, it appears I can simply calculate (conf.high - predicted value)/1.96).  Am I correct?  Or am I missing something and that is not the correct way to calculate SE for the predicted estimates. If I am wrong, any ideas on how I can do this or do I need to just use CI's?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Do you want se on the parameters or the predictions? You can get the latter using `pedict(glm(...), se.fit=TRUE)`.

Comment: `predict` actually with an _r_, R is typo-sensitive ;)

Comment: Hahaha yeah those typos in R will get you every time. Thanks. Yes, I would like the SE for the predictions not the parameters.  Yes, what is weird is they differ enough from what I get from ggpredict estimates that is is odd to me since I thought they were coming from the same functions.  But perhaps I am wrong.  I am just not 100% sure which I should be using